# Get product Image from Review Collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection

I have a ReviewCollection, im trying to each "Review/Product" get a product image so i can pass on and display on template file:

```
public function getCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->setDateOrder();

    $arr = array();
    foreach ($collection as $_review) {
        $days = $this->returnDays($_review);
        if ($days <= $this->_days) {
            if (!isset($arr[$_review->getSku()])) {
                $arr[$_review->getSku()]['cont'] = 1;
            } else {
                $arr[$_review->getSku()]['cont']++;
            }
            $arr[$_review->getSku()]['productUrl'] = $_review->getProductUrl();
            $arr[$_review->getSku()]['productName'] = $_review->getName();
            $arr[$_review->getSku()]['productImg'] = $_review->getImage();
        }
    }
    // arsort($arr);

    return $collection;
}
```

In that case is every $_review a Model/Product ? 
Ty

Comment: Please confirm whether you want to get the reviews collection by product sku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a review from \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory method getId returns the productID that i load ProductRepositoryInterface as follow :

```
$this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
```

Then i get ImageURL with Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct as follow :

```
$imageBlock =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'category_page_grid');
$productImage->toHtml();
```

I have uploaded my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/silici0/TopReviwed) if one needed, a review of my code would be nice. Ty.

Comment: Hmm I tried this but that was more the review ID, for me getEntityPkValue() seemed to return the product id which I could then use to pull product from product repo like above.